# Forcing Serenity to use the latest chrome driver version on Jenkins

Tags: serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

How do I force serenity to use the chrome driver version installed on Jenkins? I have set the autodownload to false in serenity.conf file. But I still see that the chrome driver used to run the tests is still an older version than the one on Jenkins.
I am trying to run the tests in Jenkins pipeline. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.